# Programming RFID Tags

Tags: rfid

I'm looking into what can be done with RFID tags and I know that most RFID tags can only handle 1-2kb of data so I'm wondering if those with more experience with them will be able to inform me on my questions:

1. What sort of data can an RFID tag hold? By that I mean, it is the
   RFID tag that holds information about the stock one tag may be used
   on, or is its serial number looked up in a data base and the stock
   information is accessed that way?
2. If I was to permanently embed some RFID tags into a static structure
   would it be possible for the tag to hold its positional information
   and then have my my RFID reader get that information? If not, is
   there any other way I could go about doing that?

Comment: Flagging as off-topic, but here's some info anyway: RFID tags hold raw data, you can store whatever you want on them. Depending on your API, you'll be writing text strings or byte arrays. Most (not sure if all) tags also have a unique identifier. So you can store GPS coordinates on a tag and later read them again.

Comment: Thank you for the information but how is this an off-topic question? My question directly relates to the programming of RFID tags.

Comment: @N0xus I guess the issue is that RFID tags aren't really programmed in the right sense of the word. You don't write code for them you just write/read data into them.

Comment: @millimoose if you could have said that without using the word programmed, I'd have given you your point. But I'm still wanting to know if I can access the information I want in an RFID through code. Just because I haven't put up a code sample / specific language doesn't make it any less of a programming question. So I'm still confused as to why stijn claims this is an off topic question.

Comment: @N0xus You're arguing semantics. Human languages are ambiguous and words have more than one meaning. Programming can mean "writing a program" and it's also used to say "change the data stored in 'read-only' memory". (E.g. EEPROM.) Stack Overflow is pretty obviously about the former, and "programming a RFID chip" is clearly the latter meaning, so I don't think the fact I didn't spend 100 words to explain the difference in my argument is really all that important. Now I did, even though you obviously knew what I meant. Happy?

Comment: @N0xus As to the rest, this is still closeable as "didn't demonstrate minimal understanding". The general approach to SO is that you're expected to do as much work as possible before posting. I'd bet dollars to donuts the answer to 1. can be found on Wikipedia, if not then in the manual that comes with the tags you intend to use. The answer to 2. is still in the "try and see?" territory as well.

Comment: @millimoose I'm sorry but I can't agree with you on the points your trying to make. To me programming encompasses anything to do with writing code for what ever purpose. Wither it's seeking a better understanding of a subject related to code, a fresh pair of eyes to go over code I, and many other people I have seen, use SO for that purpose. This time, I was asking those with more experience about some certain specifics I didn't know / couldn't find about RFID tags.

Comment: @millimoose as to you latter comment, the same could be said for anything and is very ambiguous. I did my research which is why my questions where tailors to a specific aspect of data holding on an RFID chip. Though I am done debating these things with you.

Comment: @N0xus Unfortunately for you it's of no consequence whether you agree with broadly or narrowly how the Stack Overflow community interprets its mandate. I'm telling you what I think is the current groupthink with regards to moderation, and it does not consider "some code might be written at some unspecified point in the future" as "a programming problem".

Comment: @millimoose clearly. The only person I asked was stijn and then you joined in. Which has now led to this.

Comment: @N0xus Yes, I tried to explain why you got the one close vote. Because you did ask for an explanation. And seeing as I wasn't the one who cast the close vote (Stijn said he did in his comment), I'm not sure why you're trying to argue this with me - I can't make the vote go away and I wouldn't based on your argument that SO should accept a broader definition of "programming problems". All I'm telling you is what impression your question, as stated, might make on people, and what reaction it might elicit. (Although it seems that the reaction was more overwhelming disinterest.)

Comment: I only skimmed the discussion above, but the reason I flagged is that the question isn't about a problem about programming software to work with RFID tags. It's asking for info on the usage of RFID tags, which afaik is out-of-scope here. I could be wrong, but the people who review the close vote queue will decide on that. Like millimoose said: try and see. Get a test kit and documentation from your vendor and give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with UHF ISO 18000-6C tags, those are compose with four block:

```
User bank
TID bank
EPC bank
Reserved bank
```

1) You can use the `User Bank` or `EPC bank` (not recommended) and storage there any data you want to (in hexadecimal format). IMHO, I do not recomment to write down in the EPC field, because it is destined for the CRC and PR.

2) About the position, you can save any data you want. If you just want to reply with the tag position hard coded in some memory bank, that's ok.

Comment: What @BrOSs is saying is correct, just keep in mind that in UHF tags, the tags that comes with user memory, they do not have much, 512bits at most (there are a few chips that have up to 2K, but those tags are very expensive and no very common), in terms of ASCII characters, 512 bits are only 128 characters to write what ever you want. If you use HF/NFC tags, those tags have more memory, there are tags with 1K, 2K, 4K and even 8K, to write information, obviously, you can write to it and then read that information.